# Two truststore in one running JVM, is it possible? If yes then how?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have one running ejb application in websphere application server and I have two truststores, which is used for Soap webservices handshake purpose, previously we used to have only one truststore but now I have added one more, after creating one new framework for soap call and in this new framework I have setted that new ssl truststore but now problem occurs here that while starting server my handshake with server is failing intermittently 
After a lot of debugging I came to know that jvm loads only one truststore material while starting so because of that I was facing issue intermittently , now I cannot scrap my code and work on existing framework again.

So is there any other way where I can load that truststore material externally in httpclient?

Help i'll be appreciated here.

Comment: Either create separate instances of [`SSLContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html) for each SOAP client, or just combine the truststores. It depends on what your thread model is as to whether the latter suggestion is feasible.

Comment: Externally I have to load a ssl context? How we load sslContext externally that is what my concern is.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what your comment means.

Comment: SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(new File("//your jks file path "), "//key password here",
                    new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build(); is it OK to use this, mean context loading externally is OK by providing my trust material file?

Answer (score 0):

So on a specific intersection in your app you have to decide which url to call. On this intersection you can decide which truststore to use. Now don't set the global `TrustStore`, just create a new `SSLContext` with the truststore to use and get a connection of that one.

Comment: That I alredy have done, created sslcontext.but is it good practise I am just concerned about that. And I'll you please elobrate your answer more, I mean explane me with an example of best practice?